# Three years: current (2012), last (2011), but is there a term then for 2010?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, dates

I have three years I am putting on a chart: current year, last year, and I'm not sure what to call the year that came before the last. Does it have a name? Would it be "pre-last"?

Comment: The year that came *after* the last - is the current one ;)

Comment: Think *day before yesterday*.

Comment: Year before yesteryear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "**year before last**" is what one would normally say.

Comment: Also, "two years prior" or "two years ago".

Comment: @Stella No, just a lack of research.